# Clipping a raster by polygon and getting the sum of pixel values in webapplication

Tags: raster, clip, fiona, rasterio

I am loading a layer with points and a raster one in an OL2 map. The layers come from a geoserver. What I want to do is to apply some buffers to the points and based on the buffer to get the sum of the values of the raster.

I think I could do use rasterio or fiona for something like that. Or another alternative would be to run the analysis on postgres. But I was wondering if there is some javascript library for doing these kind of analysis.

Comment: If you go the rasterio route then check out rasterstats:  https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) has a bunch of raster plugins, but they seem mostly based around visualization than what you want.

If you're OK with R, that could do what you want, although it might not be as interactive as something like javascript could do. [Here's](http://zevross.com/blog/2015/03/30/map-and-analyze-raster-data-in-r/) an example that shows some raster analysis.

[This](https://pakillo.github.io/R-GIS-tutorial/) also seems useful

EDIT: I completely forgot, you could use [this](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) to generate and manipulate leaflet maps from R, so R does all the heavy lifting, and you still get responsive interactive maps from leaflet

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, GIS.SE should have standalone answers. If you are going to link out to more detailed solutions, please provide a brief synopsis of what is at the destination rather than a bare link (the two "this" hyperlinks).